# Prepared statement killing script

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a function that is supposed to get some API tokens from the DB.
Having tested the script I found that the line that prepares the SQL statement is **killing the script**:

```
static function get_tokens($platform, $is_breaking_news = 0, $in_test_mode=0) // 1-android, 2-ios
{

    global $dbh;
    $paid =2;
    $status = 1;
    $result = array();
    $query = '
        SELECT
            mobile_install_device_token, mobile_install_id
        FROM
            ' . TABLE_PREFIX . 'mobile_installs
        WHERE
            mobile_install_platform = :platform
        AND
            mobile_install_app_type = :paid
        AND ';
    if ($is_breaking_news)
    {
        $query .= '
            mobile_install_pn_status > :status
        ';
        $status = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        $query .= '
            mobile_install_pn_status = :status
        ';
    }

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query); // **THIS IS THE KILLER!**

    try
    {
        $stmt->bindParam(':platform', $platform);
        $stmt->bindParam(':paid', $paid);
        $stmt->bindParam(':status', $status);

        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {

       Utils::sql_fail($query, $e->getMessage());
    }

    while($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
    if ($in_test_mode)
    {

        if (!in_array($row['mobile_install_id'], array(4, 5, 13, 8)))
        {

            continue;
        }
    }
    echo 'send to ' . $row['mobile_install_id'] . PHP_EOL;
        $result[] = $row['mobile_install_device_token'];
    }

    return $result;
}//end function get_tokens
```

I found that it is a [known bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36652), but the solutions offered there didn't seems to work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly are things failing how and with what error message? (Edit: ah, I see now, reading the bug report. Maybe clarify that it's dying completely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug you linked to is almost a *decade* old.
One have to perform a **certain set of actions** before starting even thinking of a bug.

- turn `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` and **verify** if it was set and working
- echo your final query out.
- substitute named placeholders with actual sample data and run it in a console
- substitute named placeholders with question marks and try to prepare in in a console

like this:

```
 PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'put your query here';
```

From your question it is unclear if you completed any of the items above.
If you completed them all and all worked all right - then, there is a bug. Post a reproduceable code on PHP.NET bugtracker.
But if you get an error from any of it - just work the error out.

**Update**
Just spotted it:
For some reason you put `prepare` away from `try` block.
No wonder it is killing your code silently.

So, move `prepare` inside of `try` block.
Also, it is essential to set up error reporting.

on a development server you have to set `display_errors` to **on**, to be notified of the errors instead of silent death.
on a production server `display_errors` to **off** while `log_errors` to **on** - and look for the errors in the log in such case.

Comment: Additionally, there's a `try...catch` block but `$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);` is left out of it.